# Simple Question about CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: iphone, xcode4, linker-errors, ios5, cgrect

I just have one simple question.  Everytime I use

```
CGRectIntersectsRect(view1.frame, view2.frame)
```

I get a linker error stating the linker cannot find the files necessary to compile this method.  I do have *QuartzCore* imported, I'm assuming theres another header I need. Sadly scouring the internet has left me nowhere, and I known this is definetely a simple issue that I keep overlooking.  Any answers are appreciated!

**Notice: I am using XCode 4 and iOS 5 beta**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import the CoreGraphics framework also. (Not 100% how to think about the distinction between this and QuartzCore, but they are different.)

Answer (score 0):

You want `CGRectIntersectsRect`, not `GCRectIntersectsRect`. Make sure you also import the frameworks into your project.

**EDIT:** Did you add the `QuartzCore` framework to your project? If not, click on the blue project icon in the top left of Xcode under ***Run***, click on the ***target***, and under the ***Build Phases*** tab, select the ***Link Binary with Libraries*** option, click on the ***+***, and then add the `QuartzCore` framework.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally posted the wrong method name. Still errors though :/